# Regular expression to match square bracket url tags

Tags: regex

I'm trying to create a regular expression that will match square bracket url tags as follows:-

```
[url]some text[/url]
```

or

```
[url class="class"]some text[\url]
```

This is the pattern I have created

```
(\[url.*\])(.*?)(\[\\url\])
```

It works fine if there is only one tag however if I have two tags in a sentence as follows:

```
This is a sentence [url]blah[\url] this is another sentence[url]blah[\url]
```

It only has one match and grabs everything between the first opening and last closing `[url]` tag. I did some research and added the `?` to stop it being greedy and grabbing everything but it doesn't work. I also tried using:

```
[^\[]*
```

instead of

```
(.*?)
```

again it doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

It's the first `.*` in your regex that's causing it not to work properly. Try this:

```
(\[url[^\]]*\])([^\[]*)(\[\\url\])
```

---

`.*` is being greedy and matches everything. If you check this group from your current regex, you'll actually see `[url]blah[\url] this is another sentence[url]` as the match, `blah` in the second group and `[\url]` in the third group.

Comment: Many thanks. I dont use regular expressions often and didn't notice the first .*

Answer (score 0):

`.*` can be a bit dangerous, if you know in advance you are goig to have text/numbers you coud use `[a-zA-Z0-9]` and avoid that problem.

Something like: `\[url\][a-zA-Z0-9]+\[\\url\]`

Answer (score 0):

To be more specific , you can give:

```
(\[url( .+[=].+\])*)[z-zA-Z0-9 ](\[\url\])
```

Answer (score 0):

For `url` tags only:

```
(?:\[url])([^\[]+)\[[\/\\]url]
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/aB8mX2/3)

To remove all tags:

```
(?:\[(\w+)[^]]*]).*?\[[\/\\]\1]
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/VOAk1V/1)